# Spring Dynamic Modules and Netbeans Platform

Tags: spring, netbeans-platform, spring-dm

Has anyone integrated Spring Dynamic Modules (or Eclipse Gemini Blueprint) with Netbeans Platform? I cannot find any information on this.

I was thinking about potential use of Spring Services within the Netbeans Platform Application. Is this reasonable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Spring Dynamic Modules, but as long as it produces regular Spring services and DAOs, it's totally do-able.  I outlined the process [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049146/836738).  I am now also considering writing up a blog post complete with code examples on this topic since this seems to be a common issue.  I'll update this answer with a link as soon as I'm done.