# Whats the best practice around when to start a new session or transaction for batch jobs using spring/hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session, transactions

I have set of batch/cron jobs in Java that call my service classes. I'm using Hibernate and Spring as well.

Originally the batch layer was always creating an outer transaction, and then the batch job will call a service to get a list of objects from the DB w/ the same session, then call a service to process each object separately. Theres a tx-advice set for my service layer to rollback on any throwable. So if on the 5th object theres an exception, the first 4 objects that were processed gets rolled back too because they were all part of the same transaction.

So i was thinking this outer transaction created in the batch layer was unnecessary. I removed that, and now i call a service to get a list of objects. THen call another service to process each object separately, and if one of those objects fail, the other ones will still persist because its a new transaction/session for each service call. But the problem I have here now is after getting a list of objects, when i pass each object to a service to process, if i try to get one of the properties i get a lazy initialization error because the session used to load that object (from the list) is closed.

Some options i thought of were to just get a list of IDs in the batch job and pass each id to a service and the service will retrieve the whole object in that one session and process it. Another one is to set lazy loading to false for that object's attributes, but this would load everything everytime even if sometimes the nested attributes aren't needed.

I could always go back to the way it was originally w/ the outer transaction around every batch job, and then create another transaction in the batch job before each call to the service for processing each individual object...

What's the best practice for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Well I would say that you listed every possible option except [OpenSessionInView](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView).  That would keep your session alive across transactions, but it's difficult to implement properly.  So difficult that it's considered an AntiPattern by [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice).

However, since you're not implementing a web interface and you aren't dealing with a highly threaded environment, I would say that's the way to go.  It's not like you're passing entities to views.  Your biggest fear is an N+1 call to the database while iterating through a collection, but since this is a cron job, performance *may* not be a major issue when compared with code cleanliness.  If you're really worried about it, just make sure you get all of your collections via a call to a DAO who can do a select *.

Additionally, you were effectively doing an Open Session In View before when you were doing everything in the same transaction.  In Spring, Sessions are opened on a per transaction basis, so keeping a transaction open a long period of time is effectively the same as keeping a Session open a long period of time.  The only real difference in your case will be the fact that you can commit periodically without fear of a lazy initialization error down the road.

***Edit***

All that being said, it takes a bit of time to set up an Open Session in View, so unless you have any particular issues against doing everything in the same transaction, you might consider just going back to that.

Also, I just noticed that you mentioned opening a transaction in the batch layer and then opening "mini transactions" in the Service layer.  This is most emphatically NOT a good idea.  Spring's annotation driven transactions will piggyback on any currently open transaction in the session.  This means that transactions that are supposed to be read-only will suddenly become read-write if the currently open transaction is read-write.  Additionally, the Session won't be flushed until the outermost transaction is finished anyways, so there's no point in marking the Service layer with `@Transactional`.  Putting `@Transactional` on multiple layers only lends to a false sense of security.

I actually [blogged about this issue](http://timonjava.blogspot.com/2011/06/springhibernatejpa-and-transactions.html) some time ago.