# Spring MVC + Hibernate: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I know this topic has been discussed before, but unfortumately none of the solutions I saw works in my case, and I've been breaking my head on this for days now.

I have a typical spring-mvc web app with two contexts, servlet-context and application-conext:

This is the **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The **servlet-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cookit.cookit.controller, com.cookit.cookit.dao, com.cookit.cookit.service." />

</beans:beans>
```

And, the **application-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties, classpath:hibernate.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cookit.cookit.dao, com.cookit.cookit.service" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.cookit.cookit.domain.Ingredient</value>
            <value>com.cookit.cookit.domain.Recipe</value>
            <value>com.cookit.cookit.domain.Step</value>
            <value>com.cookit.cookit.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

I get the following error when querying for user #1, by the url: `http://localhost:8080/CookIt/user?id=1`:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to
>   thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional
>   one here

What's wrong here?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not configured transaction yet :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* YOUR.PACKAGE..*.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```

Also, You need to specify a filter in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This filter extends Hibernate session to the view.

For more inf see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it! I will try this configuration. One thing about this solution though, is the fact that OSIV is controversial one considered by some a bad practice or an anti-pattern. See here for more info [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: I actually forget to add that you need that filter config if you are going to lazily query your Hibernate domain objects (ex: parent.getChildren()) in your view