# Best way to show hibernate query results in jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm

Since the "open session in view" pattern have some drawbacks (see [Why is Hibernate Open Session in View considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice)), I am wondering what is considered the best approach in displaying results from a hibernate query to a jsp page?

One method I thought of is put a java.util.list object in the request and output the contents to the jsp page. Are there other/better methods?

Comment: The way I understand why OSIV is a bad practice is that you pass your DB objects into your front end software - a simple generic example would be to have DTO out of your entity objects, created by your backend and passed to your frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use DTO projections for your UI views. This way you can avoid `LazyInitializationExceptions` and make sure you only fetch what you need in a certain view. From a performance point of view, nothing beats an SQL projection anyway.

The DTO projection looks like this:

```
select new my.package.UserInfo(u.name, u.age, u.gender)
from Users u
```

Comment: not sure I understand because I am new in hibernate. When you say DTO projections do you mean using Criteria Queries?

Comment: You can use both Criteria and HQL. The goal is to select everything into a DTO, instead of a root Entity.

Comment: can you provide an example on selecting it all in a DTO? Do you mean something like this? session.createQuery(hql).list()

Comment: Done. But if you don't mind can you also provide an example on selecting it all in a DTO? I'm now studdiing how to do this but it would be really great if you provide an example for reference. Thanks.

Comment: we would put the result of the query to a list right? So is binding the list to a request object a great solution?

Comment: You get a LIst<UserInfo> from this query, which you can then use it in a root response object, if that's what you want.

Comment: thanks. I think I can use it like this: request.setAttribute("userInfo",userInfoList); or ther is a better way...

Comment: You can use it like that.