# Hibernate - Same operation launched several times become slower and slower

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, session

I have a performance problem with Hibernate.

```
Hibernate : 3.2.6.ga
JDK : jdk1.6.0_45
```

I have a function witch is annotated @Transactionnal which is linked to an EntityManager.

This function is called in a loop so I have :

```
for (Item i : itemList) 
{
saveIt(i);
}
```

It's ok if I launch it 5/10/20 times, the process time doesn't seem to increase.
But if I launch it 300/400 times, the time to "saveit" is slower and slower ...
I monitored the java memory and I didn't see something strange.

So I found some article talking about the Flush/Clean magic solution.
I tried it and hourra, it works.

```
for (Item i : itemList) 
    {
    saveit(i);
    cleanMySession();
    }
```

But to me it's quite strange, because I thought that the @Transactionnal annotation managed all this stuff, specially when I don't do anything else related to Hibernate outside this loop ... Maybe I am a little bit lost ...

**Final question : is this workaround safe ?**

Note : in reality, the saveIt function is quite huge in term of data manipulation, so the process time is quite important and must not increase.

EDIT - Additional information :

I stopped in debug mode in my cleanSession function :

```
public void cleanSession() {
    Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    session.flush();
    session.clear(); 
}
```

Here is the stack :

```
MyServiceImpl.cleanSession() line: 177  
GeneratedMethodAccessor216.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available 
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 319 
JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 196   
$Proxy40.cleanSession() line: not available 
MyAction.doSave() line: 814 
StrutsStack...
```

So yes I see some Proxy but to me, this proxy comes from Spring Injection and not from Hibernate.

Edit N°2 :

Yes I use the OpenSessionInView filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: What is the name of the method containing the for loop ? Could you report it in the Stack too (if you filtered it) ?

Comment: It's the "doSave" in MyAction class. It's the Struts controller class.

Comment: Ok so i guess that the for loop is in the `MyAction.doSave()` method. And you have no other $Proxy in the stack (above in the stack, below in the printed stacktrace) than the $Proxy40 ? Do you use the openSessionInViewFilter ?

Comment: New edit with the filter.

Comment: i've updated my answer to add info about why the openSessionInViewFilter trigger the behavior you see

Comment: Thank you Thierry. Now it is clear. As you said, I won't remove it but I will be careful if I have to design a new app from 0. Have a nice day.

Comment: You were using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and not OpenSessionInView filter as mentioned in the edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the method `cleanMySession()` works where you put it (inside the for loop, but outside the `saveIt()` method shows that you already have a transaction open before you start the for loop. As a consequence, all the action you do in the for loop is done in only one tx, with only one session whose size will keep growing, slowing down the `flush` operations (dirty check).

You'll need to refactor the service call to ensure no transaction exists before making a call to `saveIt()`.

To pinpoint where the unwanted transaction is open, just set a breakpoint at the start of the for loop, get there with a runtime, and see the stacktrace. When you start seeing $Proxyxxx classes, the next method will be one opening the transaction.

it will look like that in the stack :

```
at ... <- the method with @Transactional annotation here ->
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy452.handle(Unknown Source)
...
```

If you have other aspects than the `@Transactional` one configured, you might encounter proxies on method not annotated with `@Transactional`, just keep looking in the stack call

EDIT: 
The whole Http Request will have one tx opened by the filter : view it as if you annotated the Controller (the view generation included) with @Transactional.

This filter is considered bad (have a look at [Why is Hibernate Open Session in View considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice)), but if your application is big, removing it might be complex and painful.

Your workaround should work.

If you need to commit several times, you could look into `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`... But with this, each request will hog several connections to the database (1 for the filter + 1 per nested level of `REQUIRES_NEW`), and might fail in the middle because there is no more connection in the pool when it encounters a 'requires_new' method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have a good point about the fact that I probably have a transaction opened before (but where ?) and that was the purpose of my question. The project I work on is quite messy and I try to figure out where are the big structural issues. I will search deeply. Thanks.